# AWS Redirecting traffic to correct region

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I have an app hosted on 2 VMs in different regions (Say US and Australia). Users will have their data on either of these regions because of data residency constraints.

Let's say a user whose data is on AU server is travelling to Canada and Geographical/Latency based routing will route the user to closest server that is US.

My App can internally somehow respond to redirect this user to AU server. How can i make all subsequent requests go to AU server directly without going to US server?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have configured a DNS Name in Amazon Route 53 to use Georouting or Latency-Based Routing to direct users to a destination.

To direct the user to a *different* location, you could need to send them to an IP address or DNS Name that does *not* go through this georouting/latency lookup.

For example:

- Create `sydney.example.com` to point to the Sydney server
- Create `ohio.example.com` to point to the Ohio server
- Create `example.com` to use geo/latency routing that resolves to either `sydney.` or `ohio.`
- When you want to redirect a user to a specific location (eg Sydney), send them to `sydney.example.com` to avoid going through the geo/latency lookup again

Comment: That's not the solution I am looking for. I have a public API that will be exposed on a common URL (api.example.com).
I am planning to use AWS Global Accelerator to manage multi-region architecture. Any suggestions in this direction?

Comment: There is no capability to specify an 'override' for Amazon Route 53 or Global Accelerator. That's why you'll also need a way to send users to a _specific_ destination.

Comment: Then, how do public APIs, (let's say api.facebook.com) works while the data of users is being hosted in the user-specific countries only. But still, they are able to provide data using a common domain name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to architecturally separate data residency requirements of a given user's profile data, from performance considerations of content delivery - this will help you get farther along on both tracks.

For example, data residency of a user is typically decided at account creation time and rarely changes subsequently. Your "data at rest" stays in Australia for example. The data at rest may be exposed to *all* your application servers globally  (including those booted up in a Canadian data center) using uniform internal API or database-host accessing schemes.

The above architecture will allow at-rest data to be in Australia, but "data in transit" or cached-in-memory data (e.g any KV store) to be accessible from any application server "worker" anywhere in the world. Make sure you use encryption while the data is in transit, and audit any persistence of the said data.

You can layer on further performance by maximising HTTP responses that are cacheable freely by CDNs and any intermediary caches (the `Cache-Control` HTTP header), as well as using the geo-routing strategies you already mention.